# Binding problems with using Selector and Messaging in Monotouch

Tags: binding, xamarin.ios

I've been trying to reproduce this [Animate a view zoom-bouncing in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6132933/animate-a-view-zoom-bouncing-in)
in Monotouch but I hit an exception and I don't know what to do...
these statics methods are in a utility class.
An exception is raised on the sending the message to the first selector.

> MonoTouch.Foundation.MonoTouchException: Objective-C exception thrown.  Name: NSInvalidArgumentException Reason: -[MainScreen bounce1AnimationStopped]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x13908570
>     at at (wrapper managed-to-native) MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Messaging:void_objc_msgSend_IntPtr_IntPtr (intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr)
>     at AnimationManager.BounceAppear (MonoTouch.UIKit.UIViewController container, MonoTouch.UIKit.UIView view, Double duration) [0x0003a]

```
    public static void BounceAppear(UIViewController container, UIView view, double duration = 0.5)
    {
        view.Transform = CGAffineTransform.MakeScale(0.001f, 0.001f);
        UIView.BeginAnimations(null);
        UIView.SetAnimationDuration(0.3f/1.5f);
        UIView.SetAnimationDelegate(container);
        var selector = new MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Selector("bounce1AnimationStopped");
        Messaging.void_objc_msgSend_IntPtr_IntPtr(container.Handle, selector.Handle, container.Handle, view.Handle);
        UIView.SetAnimationDidStopSelector(selector);
        view.Transform = CGAffineTransform.MakeScale(1.1f, 1.1f);
        UIView.CommitAnimations();
    }

    [Export("bounce1AnimationStopped:forView")]
    public static void Bounce1AnimationStopped(UIViewController container,UIView view)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Bounce1AnimationStopped");
        UIView.BeginAnimations(null);
        UIView.SetAnimationDuration(0.3f/2.0f);
        UIView.SetAnimationDelegate(container);
        var selector = new MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Selector("bounce2AnimationStopped");
        Messaging.void_objc_msgSend_IntPtr_IntPtr(container.Handle, selector.Handle, container.Handle, view.Handle);
        view.Transform = CGAffineTransform.MakeScale(0.9f,0.9f);
        UIView.CommitAnimations();
    }

    [Export("bounce2AnimationStopped:forView")]
    public static void Bounce2AnimationStopped(UIViewController container, UIView view)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Bounce2AnimationStopped");
        UIView.BeginAnimations(null);
        UIView.SetAnimationDuration(0.3f/2.0f);
        view.Transform = CGAffineTransform.MakeIdentity();
        UIView.CommitAnimations();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I forgot to register my class and have its reference pass to the messaging function

```
private static IntPtr class_ptr = Class.GetHandle("animationManager");
```

and then

```
Messaging.void_objc_msgSend_IntPtr_IntPtr(class_ptr, selector.Handle, container.Handle, view.Handle);
```