# CGAffineTransform off of a transform

Tags: ios, transform

So I have this transform (`UIView` animate) that scales it to 0.4 and I want to do another transform to 0.0 from that 0.4. But when I try that it doesn't work and it doesn't animate, it just pops (no animation).

Comment: Can you share your code? I mean, what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

If you scale to 0.0 the view will vanish, if you want it to go 'back' then you want to animate the view back to `CGAffineTransformIdentity`

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6132933/animate-a-view-zoom-bouncing-in) for an example of a scaling 'bounce' animation that uses nested animation calls.

If you're doing something drastically different then you'll have to provide source code of what you're doing and explain what effect you're after so we can help.