# How to do zoom in and transform animation?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiimageview, core-animation

It is clear how to do a zoom in/scaling [animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6132933/animate-a-view-zoom-bouncing-in) and how to animate an image changing to [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2834573/how-to-animate-the-change-of-image-in-an-uiimageview). But I need an image to zoom in and midway transform to another. How can it be done?

Comment: please share your code and explain in detail

Comment: @JigneshMayani - There is no associated code. I need an UIImage to get bigger and before the animation ends I need to change the image in it with animation (no abrupt change).

Comment: You could try to make two image overlap on top of each other and add some kind of transition which change the opacity of one image to make it more transparent over time.

Answer (score 1):

This code will work for you.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 animations:^{
    imgView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.5, 1.5);
}
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     [UIView transitionWithView:self.view
                                       duration:2.0f
                                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                                     animations:^{
                                         [imgView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"default_avatar"]];
                                         imgView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(2.0, 2.0);
                                     } completion:nil];
                        }];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
 [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 animations:^{
        self.imgView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.5, 1.5);
    }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){

                         _imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"3D_search"];
                         [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 animations:^{

                             self.imgView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(2.0, 2.0);
                         }];
                     }];
```

Comment: The image change is abrupt here. I tried putting the change in animation also. But the timing is not fitting.